# There is a random backslash on top of my table

Tags: javascript, html, css

Somebody please help me. My html keeps putting a backslash "\" on top of my table. I don't know how else to explain it. It's just there. If I comment out my table tag it goes away. If I view the HTML through dev tools, it displays the slash as:

```
"
        \
                " ==$0
```

I have scripts on the page, but I've tried commenting all of them out... It still creates this random backslash. Here's the HTML segment in question.

```
<div id="name_e" class="tabcontent" style="display: block">
        <h2>MY NAME</h2>
        <h3>Contact Information</h3>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Phone Number:</th>
                <td>555-555-5555</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Email Address:</th>\
                <td>email@gmail.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Address:</th>
                <td>111 Address Road</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>City:</th>
                <td>Cityville</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>State:</th>
                <td>Atlantis</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Zip Code:</th>
                <td>55555</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

So... I'm lost. I'm totally lost. Please help. I'm out of ideas here...

[image: picture]

Comment: ` <th>Email Address:</th>\` You have a slash here.

Comment: `<th>Email Address:</th>\`

Comment: I am so sad. I got so frustrated over something so stupid... Welp. Thanks.

Comment: It happens, no worries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never have to be lost with something like this. There are many strategies for finding this kind of bug; here are a few of them. You've probably already thought of the first one:

#### Ctrl+F (or Command+F)

Since you know the problem is a spurious backslash, search your code for that character, and there you find it.

#### Divide and Conquer

One of the most traditional debugging techniques, and one that often works with problems that are much harder to spot.

Take your code with the bug and then simply start removing pieces of it, one by one, until the bug goes away.

Sometimes this is done by removing half the code and re-testing. If the bug goes away, then it was probably in the code you took out. If it's still there, then it is in the code you still have. Then you can repeat this process on one half or the other until you narrow down the problem.

Or, for a small HTML table like yours, you can start removing entire `<tr>`...`</tr>` sections one. If you got all the way to where all the rows were gone, then delete the entire table. And continue from there. (Of course in this example you would have found the problem before that.)

#### Use the HTML Validator

For HTML problems, it's always a good idea to check your HTML code in the [W3C Validator](https://validator.w3.org/). You can have it load a URL, or paste your HTML code directly into the "Direct Input" tab.

You'll need to provide an entire HTML document, so yours might look like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="name_e" class="tabcontent" style="display: block">
        <h2>MY NAME</h2>
        <h3>Contact Information</h3>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Phone Number:</th>
                <td>555-555-5555</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Email Address:</th>\
                <td>email@gmail.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Address:</th>
                <td>111 Address Road</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>City:</th>
                <td>Cityville</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>State:</th>
                <td>Atlantis</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Zip Code:</th>
                <td>55555</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you paste that into the validator you will get this error:

```
Error: Misplaced non-space characters inside a table.
From line 16, column 40; to line 17, column 20
ress:</th>\↩                <td>email@
```

Comment: These are all excellent tools! Thank you for giving me the skills necessary to prevent an embarrassing error like this from showing up on StackOverflow again.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your slash:

```
<th>Email Address:</th>\
```

Every literal within a `<table>` that is not contained within the `<td>`, `<th>` and other containers is invalid HTML and displayed above the table.